Inconsistent class path between Byte Buddy and Mockito
I'm having some issues with the integration between Mockito and JUnit5.
The problem seems to be caused by:
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException:
It seems like you are running Mockito with an incomplete or inconsistent class path. Byte Buddy could not be loaded.

My dependency tree is:
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-inline:jar:4.11.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.11.0:test
[INFO] |     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.19:test
[INFO] |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.11.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.9:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.32.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.27.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:compile

I have the following surefire plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
</plugin>

I've managed to solve it by adding the following dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

But then I encounter the folllowing issue:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver

Even though I have no clue how can this be related I show my entityManagerFactory:
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
                hibernate.query.substitutions=${hibernate.substitutions}
                hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=${hibernate.use.secondLevelCache}
                hibernate.cache.provider_class=${hibernate.cacheProvider.class}
                hibernate.show_sql=${hibernate.cacheProvider.show.sql}
            </value>
        </property>
</bean>


I suspect using a too new version of ByteBuddy for the version of Hibernate you are using (or reasoned the other way your Hibernate version is too old to support this version of ByteBuddy).

As you said there is a conflict between the version needed by hibernate-core of ByteBuddy and the one needed by mockito. I've check for compatible versions and find out hibernate 5.6.7.Final and mockito 4.4.0 use the same version of ByteBuddy

Are you sure Byte Buddy is only in test scope? Normally, the latest version of Byte Buddy should be compatible with older consumers.

No, it is also present in my Hibernate dependency: org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.32.Final:compile +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:compile when byte-buddy dependencies are explicitly added (as tests dependencies) tests can be run but then I encounter the second issue

I have faced that same issue with hibernate 5.4.33 and mockito 4.11, so, the solution for me was to either downgrade/update mockito or update/downgrade hibernate and play with these versions as needed.
